# How to share different items for activities with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to share different items for activities type.
For facebook:I have to share: text & url.
but for Mail:I have to share text,image & url.

I have seen many questions but none answered my queries.

Below is the piece of code, How I'm doing it.

```
@IBAction func shareDetails(sender: AnyObject) {

    var activityItemsArray:[AnyObject] = [SharingProvider(source: detail)]
    if let urlString = dealer.websiteURL {
        if let url = NSURL(string:urlString) {
            activityItemsArray.append(url)
        }
    }

    let shareVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItemsArray, applicationActivities: nil)
    shareVC.setValue("This is the Subject", forKey: "subject")

    shareVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType:String!, completed:Bool, returnedItems:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if !completed {
            return
        }
    }

    self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to customize activityItemArray based on activityType.
Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way is using `UIActivityViewController` for example in the following way :

```
@IBAction func shareSheet(sender: AnyObject) {

let firstActivityItem = "Text you want"
let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http//:urlyouwant")!
// If you want to put an image
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!

let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem, image], applicationActivities: nil)

// This lines is for the popover you need to show in iPad 
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as! UIButton)

// This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)

// Anything you want to exclude
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
    UIActivityTypePrint,
    UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
    UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
    UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
    UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
    UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo
]

self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The above code works for both iPhone and iPad because in you set the new `popoverPresentationController` in iOS 8 it works for iPad too.

In the case of use an `UIBarButtonItem` you need to replace this line:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as! UIButton)
```

With this one:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = (sender as! UIBarButtonItem)
```

I hope this help you.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30111284/4519527)